# unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key

Tags: ios, swift, pod

Пытался залить архив в тест флай. Операция завершается успешно, но потом мне приходит письмо на почту:

Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at '/Payload/App_Name/Target Support Files/Alamofire/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.

И эта ошибка касается всех поих подфайлов. Я пробовал сделать так как описано в этом письме. Но тогда я вообще не могу запустить свое приложение даже на симуляторе. Все ответы на стеке прошерстил. Так и не нашел того, что решил бы мою проблему.

Comment: Уже третий день мучаюсь :(

Comment: Решение было найдено!

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста найденное решение как ответ, на случай если у кого возникнет такая же проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, солюшен следующий: В Build Phases в CopyBundle Resources не должно быть таких файлов как info.plist или папок содержащих такие файлы. Если ты их находишь, то сразу удаляй и вуйаля.